# shared memory between C++ and Rust

Tags: c++, rust, shared-memory

I have a C++ application, that spawns a child Rust binary via fork/exec.

How do I create shared memory between C++ and Rust?
In C++ I can use `shmget` to create a shared memory block, what do I do on the Rust side?

Thanks.

Comment: the same I guess

Comment: With the [`libc` crate](https://crates.io/crates/libc) and some `unsafe` code you can do anything you want.

Comment: Note that if you only need a couple of libc's functions and don't want the external dependency, you can bind them yourself (rust links with libc by default).

Comment: How do I pass reference to shared memory from c to Rust?

Comment: Use the same `key` in C and Rust. Or use the newer POSIX API [`shm_open`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open)+[`mmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with the same name on both sides.

Comment: I suggest using any library for IPC.